# How I put a name for a Thread shedule in Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, scheduling

I've a Java class that has plent of schedule, but a want to set a name for the schedule, but I don´t know. When I work with Java Time, it is possible, but in Spring how do it?
I need to set a name becouse, im my system i´ve a lot of Java Thread.

- With Java Time
  new Timer("My Thread")).scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()

-With Spring ?

```
@Scheduled(cron = "00 00 06 * * ?", zone = TIME_ZONE)
@Scheduled(cron = "00 00 11 * * ?", zone = TIME_ZONE)
@Scheduled(cron = "00 00 16 * * ?", zone = TIME_ZONE)
@Scheduled(cron = "00 00 19 * * ?", zone = TIME_ZONE)
@Scheduled(cron = "00 00 22 * * ?", zone = TIME_ZONE)
public void updateCacheEmployee() {

    funcionarioRepository.listAllEmployeeByRFID(Utility.FORCE_UPDATE);
    funcionarioRepository.listAllEmployeeByFingerPrint(Utility.FORCE_UPDATE);
    Utility.print(c, ".....Update the cache: ", Utility.TYPE_ALERT);
}
```

Comment: That does not answer you question but you can just use on annotatoin @Scheduled(cron = "00 00 06/11/19/22 * * ?", zone = TIME_ZONE)

Comment: In my system, I've a lot of threads, and in some time I need to destroy or start some thread, but, existe the threads of the own Java and Spring, then, if I've named my threads, I can make an filter to skip the threads that I don't control